# typo3 GIF not playing in 9.5.4

Tags: typo3, gif, typo3-9.x

I added an animated gif to my page. It plays in the backend when adding it. It never plays in the front end: it gets replaced by a processed version.

This behavior didn't happen in 8.x. But anyway, how could I stop the processing of gif files?

Is it possible or do I have to switch the graphics processing off all together? 
Can it be made to behave like in 8.x?

Comment: I guess, the image is processed automatically to a smaller version. Can you confirm that (indicator: look at the file name in frontend. If ending like your_file_name_d281281.gif, it is processed)?

Comment: There was an option to set image_compression to None in TYPO3 V7 to not process any image, but  they removed it in TYPO3 V8:  https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/39b2cb9d02273ca9f58a1e36e6243296b8418657/typo3/sysext/core/Documentation/Changelog/8.6/Breaking-79622-CSSStyledContentAndTypoScript.rst

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure three things:

- in the TYPO3 Installation-Wide Options (aka Install Tool) you need to set `[GFX][gif_compress]` to 0
- when using the image in the frontend, check that the width of your GIF file doesn't exceed the settings of `styles.content.textmedia.maxW` and `styles.content.textmedia.maxWInText`
- if you set a width or height with cut, like the c at the end of 100 `tt_content.image.20.1.file.width = 100c`, then your gif will be converted and this is not working.

Comment: THanks Peter! Yes, the gif displayed is form the _processed_ folder. I have set 'gif_compress' => false, in the DefaultConfiguration.php but it keeps being done (maybe it is being recalled somewhere else...) As to where to check styles.content.textmedia.maxWInText I am still searching... :-) Thank you very much!!

Comment: `styles.content.textmedia.maxW` have to be set in your TypoScript constants.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you may want to mark it as "answered" so others searching for the same issue can find it more easily.

Comment: Nothing seemed to help... somewhere there is a rule that is setting the width of the columns to 530 when the media is to one side. Then I reduced the gif to 530 and it played. If the media is placed before or after it will play in the bigger size, in fact, it will even enlarge the gif without loosing the animation...